# How to move deleted data from one table to another table in database and display it in history table?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to save the data to another table in the database when successfully deleted

**Here is my delete.php code**

```
if(isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])) {

    $sql = "DELETE FROM client_info WHERE id = ?";
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);
        $param_id = trim($_POST["id"]);
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
           
        }
    } 
} else {

    if(empty(trim($_GET["id"]))) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged bootstrap-5?

Comment: My first question is, why do you want to save it to another table? I would suggest using soft deletes instead. The data stays in the same table, you don't actually delete it, but set a column `deleted` to `1`. That way you can keep the log, and restoring a row will be easy.

Comment: First, issue an _insert_ statement. Then do your _delete_. Do both within a _transaction_.

Comment: As mentioned before best solution is to soft delete the data, but if you want to move it to another table I would create a database trigger on delete statements for that table

Comment: what if i make another query? because i want to display the data in another form

Comment: You can show it in "another form", no need to put it in another table